# Using a configuration file for connman

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, buildroot, connman

I'm trying `connman` on a Buildroot environment for an RPi 3 B+.
It works, but reading the [docs](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/connman/connmanctl.1.en.html) I'm only able to connect to a WiFi network using the service names it creates (instead of the plain SSID) and I cannot understand how to use a config file instead of the interactive mode (i.e. it requires to enable the agent to feed in the password!).

Since I need to let the user to fill-in the WiFi configuration using a web page, I need a programmatically way to tell `connman` the SSID and the password of the desired WiFi network.